# How to execute script shell in Kubernetes cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I would like to run a shell script inside the Kubernetes using CronJob, here is my CronJon.yaml file :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /home/admin_/test.sh
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

CronJob has been created ( kubectl apply -f CronJob.yaml )
when I get the list of cronjob I can see the cron job ( kubectl get cj ) and when I run "kubectl get pods" I can see the pod is being created, but pod crashes.
Can anyone help me to learn how I can create a CronJob inside the Kubernetes please ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add the code for `test.sh`? you could also run `kubectl logs pod_name` to see the logs.

Comment: what does `kubectl describe pod pod-name` output?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia added the pics

Comment: logs clearly say, you don't have the script mounted in the pod and so you are getting the errors: `test.sh not found`

Comment: You are using `busybox` as image and you didn't feed the file in any way. How do you expect it to be there?

Comment: Hello @AminPashna. Please, provide the necessary details as text instead of screenshots. It's hard to work on the analysis with such outputs.

Comment: @whites11 
Can you please come up with an example of working CronJob please ?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I don't have much experience in Kubernetes, I would appreciate if you guys could come up with a working example, thanks

Comment: anyone ? any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you need to read the Kubernetes docs @AminPashna, read specifically about volumes and see how the scripts can be made available to the pod.

Answer (score 11):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you need to provide the script file in order to execute it via your `CronJob`. You can do that by mounting the file within a [volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/). For example, your `CronJob` could look like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /myscript/test.sh
            volumeMounts:
            - name: script-dir
              mountPath: /myscript
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: script-dir
            hostPath:
              path: /path/to/my/script/dir
              type: Directory
```

Example above shows how to use the [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) type of volume in order to mount the script file.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out

Comment: thanks for following up, yes, thank you very much for all the help, I could finally execute the .sh file and created a CronJob to run it.
thanks for the help

Comment: using config map is a better option